# what is wrong with my if statement

Tags: asp.net, if-statement, authentication, membership

Please help review this code even when the user is not in the role apply it fail to redirect the user to status.aspx

```
if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || !User.IsInRole("apply") || Session["ctre"].ToString() != "Court" || Session["userName"].ToString() == null)
        {
            if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || Session["userName"].ToString() == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("status.aspx");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

your condition is wronge.

try this one

```
if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || !User.IsInRole("apply") || Session["ctre"].ToString() != "Court" || Session["userName"].ToString() == null)
    {

            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");

       } else
        {
            Response.Redirect("status.aspx");
        }
```

Comment: I want to make it such that if the user is autheticated but user not in role "apply" it should go to status.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your code is

```
if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || !User.IsInRole("apply") || Session["ctre"].ToString() != "Court" || Session["userName"].ToString() == null)
{
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || Session["userName"].ToString() == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("status.aspx");
    }
}
```

There are 2 if-statements and both of them have similar conditions

```
!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || ... Session["userName"].ToString() == null 
!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ||     Session["userName"].ToString() == null
```

That probably means that first condition makes no sense and your entire code should be

```
if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || Session["userName"] == null)
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
else
    Response.Redirect("status.aspx");
```

UPDATE:

if you need to check for role, namely "if the user is autheticated but user not in role "apply" it should go to status.aspx and not login.aspx" use

```
if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || Session["userName"] == null || User.IsInRole("apply"))
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
else
    Response.Redirect("status.aspx");
```

Comment: i have different role in my website, so how do i handle the role of the user

Comment: It doesn't matter. If you have some if-condition and you see that it is passed then it means that condition is wrong. Include roles in IF-statement but keep only one IF.

Comment: the reason I'm bothered about role is that I want to make it such that if the user is autheticated but user not in role "apply" it should go to status.aspx and not login.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is duplication in your code, you may say its a code redundancy, use following conditions

```
if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || Session["userName"] == null)
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
else
    Response.Redirect("status.aspx");
```

Comment: I have 3 roles in my website that is why i included the role condition